# Adding a background to a branched div tag

Tags: html, css

I am getting into difficulty where when I try to add a branching division and adding a background to that division nothing happens.

HTML:

```
    <div class="content">
        <div id="page1">
            <center><img src="img/logo.png"/></center>
            <h3> <b>Hello</b> This is fun and friendly </h3>

            <p>People writing about how to help you fix a html problem!</p>

            <p>Thank you,</p>
            <p>John Bohn</p>
            </div>   
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
page1 {
    background-color: #00007;
}
```

Nothing happens at all with the CSS.

If anyone could help me and explain what I am doing wrong and how to fix it. I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: `<center>` is unsupported in HTML5.

Comment: What would I use to replace it?

Comment: `img{display:block; margin: 0 auto;}`

Comment: Though its not an img that I am displaying, its text.

Comment: Thanks, let me take a shot at that.

Comment: @StephenP I have attempted to use your method, though for some reason it throws it off to the left. The <center> tag is working for me. Should it not be? Am I using the improper version of html? Is that even possible?

Comment: @Colin - Mooseman's `{display:block; margin: 0 auto;}` will work on a `<div>` or `<p>` full of text just as well as it works on an `<img>`

Answer (score 2):

You need to include `#` in your css for selecting elements by id.
**[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/61x6nr1s/)**

```
#page1 {
    background-color: #00007;
}
```

`#` - id selector
`.` - class selector

```
#elementId{
    // css styles for an element with id
}

.elementClass{
    // css styles for an element with class
}

elementTagName{
    // css styles for a specific html tag
}
```

Comment: I have added '#' before the page1 and refreshed the page. It still seems to do nothing at all.

Comment: Then you have something else wrong. Do you have the css on the page in `<style></style>` in the head section? Or including an external css file in the head?

Comment: I have it in an external css file. (This is the only CSS not working for me right now)

Comment: And you are including the external file in the head section? `<head><link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/stylesheet.css" /></head>`

Answer (score 0):

Correctly it's...

```css
#page1 {
  background-color: #00007;
}
```

missed the hash (`#`) at the beginning of your selector.

Answer (score 0):

CSS prefixes work like this:

`#page1 { .... }` <--- an ID

`.page1 { .... }` <--- a class name

`page1 { ... }` <--- a tag of `<page1>`, which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Try `#page1` instead of page1

Please keep these in mind:

The # prefix refers to an id

```
<div id="page1"> 
...
#page1 { ...
```

The . prefix refers to a class

```
<div class="page1"> 
...
.page1 { ...
```

no prefix refers to an element.

```
<div> 
...
div { ...
```

There are many , many other selectors!!! Its a big world out there, I recommend you google "CSS Selectors" :)

Answer (score -2):

```
  <div class="content">
        <div id="page1">
            <center><img src="img/logo.png"/></center>
            <h3> <b>Hello</b> This is fun and friendly </h3>

            <p>People writing about how to help you fix a html problem!</p>

            <p>Thank you,</p>
            <p>John Bohn</p>
            </div>   
        </div>
    </div>


#page1 {
    background-color: #00007;
}
```

Comment: The # in the css not in the id !